# Postgres Include throws "name": "SequelizeEagerLoadingError"

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

I am having trouble figuring out why my include statement throws this error

```
"name": "SequelizeEagerLoadingError"
```

My controller function in question looks like this

```
retrieve (req, res) {
    return User
      .findOne({
        where: {
          token_id: req.params.token_id
        },
        include: [{
          model: subscribedcurrency,
          as: 'subscribed currency'
        }]
      })
      .then(user => {
        if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).send({
            message: 'User Not Found'
          })
        }
        return res.status(200).send(user)
      })
      .catch(error => res.status(400).send(error))
  },
```

The model for subscribedcurrency looks like this

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var SubscribedCurrency = sequelize.define('SubscribedCurrency', {
    symbol: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    },
    priceAtSubscription: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false
    }
  })
  SubscribedCurrency.associate = (models) => {
    SubscribedCurrency.hasMany(models.User, {
      foreignKey: 'userId',
      onDelete: 'CASCADE'
    })
  }
  return SubscribedCurrency
}
```

I've tried changing how it queries, the primary key of User, just about everything I can think of. The relationship between User and subscribedCurrency is many to many.

without the include statement and the findOne query works perfect fine!

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to remove `as: 'subscribed currency'` , as you haven't define association with alias.

So From this :

```
include: [{
    model: subscribedcurrency,
    as: 'subscribed currency'
}]
```

To this :

```
include: [{
    model: subscribedcurrency,
}]
```

Comment: Have you checked with `SubscribedCurrency` instead of `subscribedcurrency`

Comment: Yes I have, do you think I need to look into adding a join table?